# Loading multiple CSV files in QGIS and declaring encoding

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, import, encoding

By the following code from the other post, I was able to load multiple CSV files into QGIS.

```py
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/csv folder/"  

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv) 

# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

However, not all my file headers are in English: instead of
`x,y`
I have:
`"經度", "緯度"`
so I tried to declare the encoding like common python files. As a result, QGIS load up the files but failed to get the x,y and the name directory.

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/csv folder/"  

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv) 

# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y") #THE "x" AND "Y" is not in ENGLISH
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Where did I go wrong?

The one I load with ordinary ctrl+shift+T :
[image]

The one that failed with python script:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you need to also encode the field names for longitude/latitude and it will works (tested using your sample file name at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/1aa1bf66d847be043a246df8bf74793e You just need to change `path_to_csv` to your own path)

```py
import glob
import os
from urllib.parse import quote


# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "your_path"
x_field = '經度' # longitude
y_field = '緯度' # latitude

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)

for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + quote(fname) + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", quote(x_field), quote(y_field))
    # Uncomment below line and comment above line
    # if when you open the layer table you see garbage
    # characters as it will deal with UTF-8 encoding
    # using additional `encoding=UTF-8` option
    # uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + quote(fname) + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&encoding=UTF-8&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", quote(x_field), quote(y_field))
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import glob, os
import urllib.parse

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "/home/rafd/Downloads/test_data/"
#print ('encoding in use:'+ sys.getfilesystemencoding())
# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv) 

# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in os.listdir():
    if fname.endswith(".csv"):
        print('This file is named: '+urllib.parse.quote_plus(fname))
        uri =  'file://'+path_to_csv +urllib.parse.quote_plus(fname) +'?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=x&yField=y&crs=EPSG:27700&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no' 
        name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
        lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
        #print('importing: '+uri)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

On a Linux box it works also with CSVs whose filename contain chinese characters ('經度.csv'); try it out on your OS.

For further import options, the official reference is:

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html

Comment: Hi, appreciated your answer but this doesn't quite match the question.
For better understanding, I'm using Chinese letters so it's ( ",", "經度", "緯度"), but since the whole file is not declared its encoding (Even if I write # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- at the first line), QGIS cannot read the file directory.

Comment: I see: I thought "not all my files are in English (file name, x,y parameter)" meant they are not expressed in the "English" notation of CSVs (i.e. with decimal point separator).
I edited your original question to make that clear.

Comment: Also see the edited answer, with the `encoding` parameter

Comment: Could you put complete name of one file in Chinese and its two first lines?

Comment: Filename(with abs path): 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/File/鳥類.csv'
First Line :  ID,OccurrenceUUID,最後修改時間,物種學名,物種中文名,經度,緯度,界,綱,科 (經度,緯度 = longitude/latitude)

Comment: Unfortunately, QGIS still cannot load the correct path for encoding reason. I'm sure the path is correct but it doesnt first translate in utf8 then being read by QGIS. The one I load with ordinary ctrl+shift+T : https://imgur.com/PF721MX   ;      The one that failed with python script : https://imgur.com/LEsmSc3

Comment: I see now. please read the rewritten answer. Also, I will update your question to include the pictures you provided, as they clarify your needs.